# Работа с Apollo Client

Tags: android, android-studio, graphql, apollo-client

Пытаюсь подключиться к GraphQL с помощью Apollo Client, в build.gradle подключил все зависимости, добавил schame.json, добавил запросы которые мне нужны, но при Rebuild Project выдает ошибку `ERROR: Value 'main GraphQL source' specified for property '$1' cannot be converted to a file.`

Еще один вопрос, не сыроватая ли технология чтобы использовать GraphQL в своих проектах или использовать старый-добрый REST API?

**build.gradle** (project)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    classpath 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:0.4.2'
    classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync-gradle-plugin:2.8.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle** (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firstgraphqlapollo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:0.4.2'
implementation "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-android-support:0.3.2"
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Непосредственно **schema.json** и (запрос) **GetAll.graphql**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и конечно же сама ошибка((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас где-то есть файл настроек, предполагаю вот это он: 'main GraphQL source', и похоже в нём ошибка, которая выглятит вот так: '$1'. А должна выглядеть как-то иначе, возможно: $s или $i или даже %s, %i

Comment: Прошу прощения, что не сразу дал полный ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже вышла версия 1.0.0
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/releases

А вы все какую-то 0.3.х мучаете :) .

В начале года была такая проблема с `apollo-gradle-plugin`, не работал с Gradle 5.
Думаю, в 1.0.0 это уже исправлено, мигрируйте.

GraphQL сама по себе чудесная технология, и уже давно не сырая. Но и применять ее надо разумно, в простых проектах может и имеет смысл остаться у REST.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, как сменил версию появилась другая ошибка, но там была причина в GetAll.graphql, после команды query забыл указать название запроса. Исправил и все забилдилось))

Comment: Есть ли у Вас рабочая версия примера для ознакомления, я испытываю в освоении некоторые трудности. Буду очень благодарен, если окажите какую либо помощь.

Comment: Своим, к сожанению, нечем поделиться. Но у авторов библиотеки есть пример: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/tree/master/apollo-sample

Comment: Авторские примеры к сожалению выдают ошибки и не компилируются(((

Comment: Только что форкнул мастер, все там компилится без ошибок.